# CSS Animate- Slide out search bar smoothly

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am new to CSS animation and wondering if someone can assist me. I have a search bar which slides in and out via CSS animation on a button click. The slide in works fine but when it slides out it just collapses. I would like to slide out smoothly as well. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slideright">
bunch of HTML...button and input 
</div>
```

**CSS ANIMATION**

```
.slideright {
    animation-name: slideright;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideright; 

    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     

    visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes slideright {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }       
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }   
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideright {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }           
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use animations for this:

HTML:

```
<div>bunch of HTML...button and input </div>
<button>Click</button>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.slideright {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $('div').toggleClass('slideright')
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaeBbN)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: Where is the question? @WendiT